# Are we muslims engaged in tribalism?

Tags: allah, islamic-basis, sufism

As a muslim born in the ME and lived in the West for years, I have started seeing a pattern. It seems we are highly engaged in tribalism; we are not racist, we are not sexists, but we are very well tribalist. What I mean is that we dont care about anybody else other than Muslims. As if people of book, or non-believers are not human beings. Allah is Rahman and his mercy is for all, not just Muslims. We dont express anger or disgust when we hear about holocaust, Sep 11, etc. The only thing we care about are people from Muslim country.

This does not make sense to me. Our prophet was rahmaton lel alamin and Allah is Rahman, but we are so tribal and anger driven that can't even feel sadness for other human being since they are not muslim.

Do you also feel the same? Are we engaged in tribalism? How can we remedy this?

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Its a Q&A site about teachings of Islam.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define what tribalism is first; tribalism is a group feeling that originates from the family bond, which evolves into having a language and culture (tradition).

Therefore, your usage of 'tribalism' does not fit. However, I understand what you mean. You need to understand that Islam does not approve of any other religion, hence, Muslims are right not to approve as well. As for being concerned about Muslims only, then that is the only right thing to do. The Rasool (saw) said "Whoever wakes up and does not care for the Ummah is not from amongst them". He (saw) did not say "...and does not care for humanity".

The Muslim is required to care for the Muslims and not non-Muslims. That does not mean we can't help them, as long as it does not harm the Muslims or prioritize them over helping Muslims. The Rasool (saw) took care of all in his capacity as a Head of State and this is an obligation upon the authority to take care of its subjects - Muslims or not. There is no distinction in that.

Getting emotional without basis is not accepted (smiles). You should re-evaluate your metric of judgement.

Allah Knows best

Comment: "Getting emotional without basis is not accepted (smiles). You should re-evaluate your metric of judgement." This is mind reading. I have been reading and thinking about this for 14 years.
I found some of your opinion relevant. But some are not. 1) All hadith are fake unless proven otherwise (thus your hadith), 2) the time of Rasoul is very different than today and thus the ummah. For example, not 2 muslims can agree on one thought now. 3) Non-muslim used to choose not to be muslim due to personal agenda. but toady people can be good and benevolent without being muslim,

Comment: 4) this type of islamic arrogance (which is rooted in our ME culture than the teaching of Rasoul) is what has kept muslim countries in the bottom of humanity for centuries, regardless of our wealth, natural resources, social capital, and geopolitical stance. 
We are more like the fans of Yankies or Red Socks. What we only care about is that OUR religion is better than others. We dont do tahzib, we dont work hard, we lie, we cheat, we are arrogant. And we think since we pray, the prophet and Allah are on our side. I can assure you they are not seeing how pathetically arrogant and blind we are.

Comment: You've missed the point,, You've spent years thinking of it wrongly... The time of our prophet was not different because his Shariah was sent for us too. If it were different a new Shariah would have been sent. And call it arrogance or not, it is the truth. Muslims are backwards today because we have let go our Deen as a whole of life, not holding on to it. We mixed tradition and western culture with Islam - which is what you are doing, mixing the superficiality of Western concept of tolerance with Islam. Living in peace does not mean you don't recognise and acknowledge kufr. And yes,

Comment: OUR RELIGION IS BETTER. ANYONE ELSE IS GOING TO HELL. Period!!!

Comment: I just feel sorry for how we ended up. From the ummah of tolerance, rahmat, and taghva, to arrogant, empty minded, bigots! That is far away from the Rasouls vision for his ummah.

Comment: I understand your concern... Islam is established on conviction. Our core beliefs are established based on strong arguments. So our confidence in out beliefs are factual and evidence based. Granted, Muslims nowadays are not so into the facts. And yes, the Rasool (saw) lived with non-Muslims, but he did not abstain from debating their beliefs. What I am saying is that Muslims must not fall for the tolerance crap. It is not arrogance if we know for sure that non-Muslims are on the wrong. It is just that our creed provides strong and definite evidences for these beliefs, making others superficial

Comment: Here are a few links giving evidences and proofs for our beliefs

https://www.islamiqate.com/3896/their-any-proof-that-allah-revealed-the-quran-his-messenger

https://www.islamiqate.com/2089/how-would-you-prove-god-exists

https://www.islamiqate.com/3896/their-any-proof-that-allah-revealed-the-quran-his-messenger